# add a "all mail" virtual folder to all users in mailserver with postfix/dovecot and MariaDB

Tags: linux, mariadb, centos7, postfix-mta, dovecot

I am trying to add a all mails virtual folder for all the users. i tried some articles but not useful. i am using Centos 7 and mail server installed with postfix/dovecot and MariaDB. Could you please help me out for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple solution.
All you have to do is just add the alias for it at "/etc/aliases" file.
Before add it, you should decide which name(=will be target address for all mails virtual). I assumed this name is just "all" for simple explain.

[step 1] check if the below line is existed at your "/etc/postfix/main.cf" file.

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

[step 2] add alias at "/etc/aliases" as the below

```
all: user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, ........, final_user_name
```

[step 3] apply alias

```
$ newaliases
```

[step 4] That's all....

If someone send email to "all@yourdomain.com", all user can receive this email.

Comment: Nebula.OTOTO                                                                                       Hi, actually i think I have not cleared my question properly. My question is that I want something like gmail. In gmail they have all mails folder from where we can see all mails of that user. I want something same for my test users as well. Please help me for this.

Comment: Now I think I know what you really want to do. So I tried the below today. Unfortunately, I failed to set up this. I hope this is what you want and you find a way to configure it. 

http://wiki.dovecot.org/Plugins/Virtual